# How can you use popView in a view navigator app to return to the previous view?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, flex4.5

Obviously poptoFirstView returns the user to the firstView. But say I want to just return to the previous? Yes, I know the user has the back button on their mobile device. But for usability sake. Someone said you can use popView to return to the latest one. But gave no hint of how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[enter link description here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/ViewNavigator.html#popView%28%29)`popView()`was the hint!

If you don't know how to use methods, you should always first refer to the AS3 reference, in your case the part about the `ViewNavigator`'s `popView()` method: [AS3 ViewNavigator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/ViewNavigator.html#popView%28%29)